# How can an undergraduate Computer Engineer start making publications before his Thesis?

Tags: publications, research-process, computer-science, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I am interested in getting involved with research, but I don't know exactly how or what I should be doing to achieve that.

What would be the best moves to do towards the campus, teachers and/or other groups inside the university? 
Are there other ways of getting started?
What should I be doing to get noticed?

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take classes from professors you'd like to do research with. Do really well. Ask good questions. Participate. Go by office hours and talk to the prof. Show interest. Try to read and understand their work. But don't be so persistent that you become annoying. You're looking for a personal fit as well as demonstrating your interest.